# Xamarin iOS - Missing Required File Icon Error ITMS-90022 & ITMS-90023

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Running the latest stable release of Xamarin (Xamarin version: 4.1.1.3 Xamarin.iOS: 9.8.1) and trying to build my Xamarin Forms app for a release to iTunes Connect for test flight. Tried building for both AppStore and Ad-Hoc and get the same error when trying to upload the .ipa about required icon files missing for 120x120, 76x76, and 152x152 (ERROR ITMS-90022, ERROR ITMS-90023).

[2016-07-18 09:03:27 EDT] ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
[2016-07-18 09:03:27 EDT] ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."
[2016-07-18 09:03:27 EDT] ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

[image]

I'm using Assets for the App Icons and all of the app icons are uploaded, so it seems that for some reason they aren't being built/added into the .ipa properly.

I also tried downgrading to the previous version of Xamarin.iOS, and still have the same issue. Also tried building both from Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio, and still have the same issues.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Currently facing same situation..

Comment: I second ahmed roshdy answer, in my case info.plist had this: <string>Resources/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string> just removing 'Resources/' worked in my case..

Answer (score 3):

After get the latest updates in xamarin and visual studio in both Windows and Mac versions ,i found the issue in path of folder App.Icons.appiconset 
so

- First: get all latest updates of visual studio and xamarin.iOS in mac and windows
- Second: check the path of XSAppIconAssets in Info.plist to be the same of actual path of your assets

i wish the issue to be solved with you too

Answer (score 1):

It would appear you are missing the icons in the red boxes below. Please double check that you have added them to the place holders even if there is another icon of the same size elsewhere. Also try doing a clean and rebuild, maybe going so far as to deleting your `bin` and `obj` folders. I do recall an issue that changes in the AppIcons were not picked up by the build system until after it is cleaned and rebuilt, but I think that was fixed a long time ago.

[image]

Comment: Did the same: Reselected all icons, cleaned projects. Now it worked fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reference to the assets folder in the info.plist file was case sensitive!  I had an uppercase 'A' giving me:

Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset

instead of a lowercase 'a' to give:

assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset

I changed that and it worked fine!

[image]

Spent a frustrating hour or so on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by changing the target Device.

[image: Deivce build picture]