# xamarin.forms Cant release to appstore anymore since update today (15.9.2021) shows error in regards to icon sizes

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

[image]

I am getting this issue upon trying to release my app to the store.

Yesterday, everythign was fine.

I did update xamarin.forms as of today which I think is causing this. Of course, all icons are set.

Anyone else having this issue now?

Comment: his link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441983/xamarin-ios-missing-required-file-icon-error-itms-90022-itms-90023) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved itself. The Appstore transporter was down for a bit